# In scrapy, 'start_urls' not defined when passed as an input argument

Tags: python, scrapy

The following spider with fixed `start_urls` works:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class NumberOfPagesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "number_of_pages"
    allowed_domains = ["funda.nl"]

    # def __init__(self, place='amsterdam'):
    #     self.start_urls = ["http://www.funda.nl/koop/%s/" % place]

    start_urls = ["http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/"]

    le_maxpage = LinkExtractor(allow=r'%s+p\d+' % start_urls[0])

    rules = (Rule(le_maxpage, callback='get_max_page_number'),)

    def get_max_page_number(self, response):
        links = self.le_maxpage.extract_links(response)
        max_page_number = 0                                                 # Initialize the maximum page number
        for link in links:
            if link.url.count('/') == 6 and link.url.endswith('/'):         # Select only pages with a link depth of 3
                page_number = int(link.url.split("/")[-2].strip('p'))       # For example, get the number 10 out of the string 'http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/p10/'
                if page_number > max_page_number:
                    max_page_number = page_number                           # Update the maximum page number if the current value is larger than its previous value
        filename = "max_pages.txt"                         # File name with as prefix the place name
        with open(filename,'wb') as f:
            f.write('max_page_number = %s' % max_page_number)               # Write the maximum page number to a text file
```

If I run it by `scrapy crawl number_of_pages`, it writes a .txt file as expected. However, if I modify it by commenting in the `def __init__` lines and commenting out the `start_urls =` line, and try to run it with a user-defined input argument,

```
scrapy crawl number_of_pages -a place=amsterdam
```

I get the following error:

```
le_maxpage = LinkExtractor(allow=r'%s+p\d+' % start_urls[0])
NameError: name 'start_urls' is not defined
```

So according to the spider, `start_urls` is not defined, even though in the code it is fully determined in the initialization. How can I get this spider to work with `start_urls` defined by an input argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `le_maxpage` is a class level variable. When you pass the argument to `__init__`, you're creating an instance level variable `start_urls`.

You used `start_urls` in `le_maxpage`, so for the `le_maxpage` variable to work, there needs to be a class level variable named `start_urls`.

To fix this issue, you need to move your class level variables to instance level, that is to define them inside the `__init__` block.

Comment: Hi masnun, I tried simply tabbing the `le_maxpage` and `rules` lines so that they are within the `__init__` block, and this causes the spider to run. However, it does not produce the `max_pages.txt` file as before. It seems like this way, the `callback` never occurs?

Comment: Because your rules are not being set now. You may change the callback name to `parse` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Following masnun's answer, I managed to fix this. I list the updated code below for the sake of completeness.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class NumberOfPagesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "number_of_pages"
    allowed_domains = ["funda.nl"]

    def __init__(self, place='amsterdam'):
        self.start_urls = ["http://www.funda.nl/koop/%s/" % place]
        self.le_maxpage = LinkExtractor(allow=r'%s+p\d+' % self.start_urls[0])
        rules = (Rule(self.le_maxpage, ),)

    def parse(self, response):
        links = self.le_maxpage.extract_links(response)
        max_page_number = 0                                                 # Initialize the maximum page number
        for link in links:
            if link.url.count('/') == 6 and link.url.endswith('/'):         # Select only pages with a link depth of 3
                page_number = int(link.url.split("/")[-2].strip('p'))       # For example, get the number 10 out of the string 'http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/p10/'
                if page_number > max_page_number:
                    max_page_number = page_number                           # Update the maximum page number if the current value is larger than its previous value
        filename = "max_pages.txt"                         # File name with as prefix the place name
        with open(filename,'wb') as f:
            f.write('max_page_number = %s' % max_page_number)               # Write the maximum page number to a text file
```

Note that the `Rule` does not even need a `callback` because `parse` is always called.